# Rails 5.2.3 / Heroku - Why is it not possible to run postgres in production mode with squlite3 in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, heroku

I'm using Rails 5.2.3 and I'm getting an application error when I try to view my production app on Heroku pipeline & the following errors when:

- I run `heroku logs` I get: `heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"`
- I run `heroku run rails console` I get: `Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile. (LoadError)`
- I run `heroku run rails db:migrate` I get: `LoadError: Error loading the 'sqlite3' Active Record adapter. Missing a gem it depends on? sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.`

I want to use sqlite3 for development and postgres for production, so why do I need to make the sqlite3 gemfile available in production mode?

Here's my gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Here's my database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by changing my config/database.yml to:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: [my_db]
  pool: 5
  username: [myapp]
  password: [password]
```

And running: `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql a- app_name` because PostgreSQL wasn't already provisioned for my app.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this part:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Currently your production is still trying to use sqlite, as this expands to

```
production: 
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

And obviously `db/production.sqlite3` also suggests a `sqlite` database

Instead change this section to

```
production: 
  adapter: postgresql
  host: [your db host] 
  database: [your database] 
  username: [your username]
  password: [your password]
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000
```

All that being said [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/download/) is free and you really should not develop again sqlite if you will be deploying to PostgreSQL.

SQLite is great for a proof of concept because it is quick to scale up and easy to tear down with no real external dependencies but if you want to actually build an application and deploy it somewhere you should really be using a production ready database.

[Heroku DB config](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-database-connection-behavior#configuring-connections-in-rails-4-1)

[Heroku Getting started Rails 5](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails5#add-the-pg-gem)

Answer (score 0):

Your `production` setting in `database.yml` is inheriting the `development` settings - you want to change it to

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

The `url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>` is applicable if you're using Heroku. If not you can consider the credential specification format [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56399449/73831).

Answer (score 0):

Try your **database.yml** like this,

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you wrote

> I want to use sqlite3 for development and postgres for production

and I can understand because I've been there myself; feeling that postgres seems like a big step to install and "I just want something small that works".

Perhaps your reason is different, but if it is not - installing postgres will save you a lot of trouble. Postgres is free and the default installation settings will probably work great for you.

In addition to saving you the hassle of adapter and gem incompatibilities, you also sometimes have differences in the SQL-commands available (when you want to do something more advanced) and what things have high performance or not.

https://www.postgresql.org/download/

When you have a development and production environment that differs - you'll spend a lot of time fixing things that does not increase the value of whatever you are building.